# After adding controller div popup does not work

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, popup

I am using **AngularJs** to create a single web application. I have two buttons, *login* & *sign up*. When ever I click a button a directive popups from the top which was developed with **CSS**.
Here is login directive code.
`app.directive('loginDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/loginDirective.html',
    }
});`

At this point the popup shows up fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU8F8.png)
But if I add controller *loginCtrl* the popup does not work. Check the updated code.

```
app.directive('loginDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment
    templateUrl: 'app/directives/loginDirective.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
}});
```

I don't know why. Is there any conflict with the css??

```
var app =  angular.module('cbApp', ['ngStorage','ngRoute']);
app.controller("loginCtrl",['$scope', '$location', '$localStorage', 'Auth', function( $scope, $location, $localStorage, Auth){}
```

If I remove **$location** then works again...

Comment: not posssible to have the controller inside 'loginDirective.html'? Like `ng-controller="loginCtrl"`

Comment: adding ng-controller="loginCtrl" does the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The controller property means it is going to look for a controller registered to your app module called 'loginCtrl'. My guess is it's not finding it. How are you including it e.g. requireJS, a script tag, etc?

Comment: `var app =  angular.module('cbApp', ['ngStorage','ngRoute']);  
app.controller("loginCtrl",['$scope', '$location', '$localStorage', 'Auth', function( $scope, $location, $localStorage, Auth){}
`  
Did I miss any other dependency Injection?